# Simple Q about isset($_POST['submit'])

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, submit, isset

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//code here
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe the code above will not work if the user submits the form using the "enter" key.

Is this true? If so, is there another if statement I can use instead of this to cover both the user using the submit button and pressing the enter key?

Comment: I think, Some IE versions do not detect enter key as submit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if a form is posted to the server use:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // …
}
```

Comment: +1. Check if it's a POST request by, uhm, checking if it's a POST request. This is better than checking hidden inputs, hoping the button is called submit, looking out the window, etc.

Comment: Yes, unless the idea is to distinguish between different submit buttons. Different forms, I mean.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: then you still first check for a post, THEN check for particular submit button values.

Comment: @MarcB, well, you also still open `<?php` tag, the thing is — it doesn't deal with the problem ;-)

Comment: I mean, if the problem is distinguishing between different forms.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not sure if `submit` will be in POST you can use overkill method: create hidden `<input>` in this `<form>` with some unique name and verify if it in POST data:

```
<input type="hidden" name="some_name" value="OK" />
```

And in PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['some_name']) && $_POST['some_name'] == "OK") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is most likely overkill considering the question.

Comment: It's a perfectly acceptable overkill answer. If by elaborating you mean doing it for you, then `<input type="hidden" name="secret_submit" value="oho" />` and check for `secret_submit`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true, if `submit` is the default submit button.

Also, there's a `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` — I take it it would be `POST` when you submit your form or `GET` otherwise, if I understand your intention right.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand on the other answers: it's probably not true if `submit` is `input type=submit` and the enter key triggers that button.  If it's `type=img` or a `<button>`, the behavior may be different with the enter key (and may not set that `_POST` value).

Answer (score 0):

The submit should be fine if it is the only submit button on the page or the first submit button on the page if there is more than one, which is probably unlikely.

An alternative would be to use a hidden input.

e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" id="processed" name="processed" value="1" />
```

then in your submit script

```
if(isset($_POST['processed'])){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: `id` is definitely an overkill, it may be duplicated somewhere ;)

Comment: maybe, a lot of people like to have ids on their inputs that match the name and it provides an easy selector for using jQuery etc. It definitely does no harm though!

Comment: In case of duplication it *does* harm. I wouldn't say that `id` is particularly harmful here in general, but it surely doesn't deal with the problem in any way ;-)